# Enabling HSTS on Apache NiFi

Tags: security, apache-nifi, owasp, hsts

I am trying to enable HSTS (HTTP Strict Transport Security) on Apache NiFi but I was unsuccessful to located where the changes need to be done.

I found the following information about the filter that I need to apply here:

https://www.javadoc.io/static/org.apache.nifi/nifi-web-security/1.11.2/org/apache/nifi/web/security/headers/package-summary.html

Found the documentation but it was not mentioned where the changes need to be done.

Comment: Not clear why do you need it. Nifi is using https by default. HSTS used when migrating web server from http to https. So, what's your goal?